# GPS sensor Broadcom GNSS Geolocation

Tags: geolocation, tablet, broadcom

I have a problem with sensor GPS of Broadcom. My device is a Tablet Latitude 10 Dell

I use the software Sensor Diagnostic Tool that test operation of GPS, but i receive message The pipe is closed (exception HResult: 0x800700E8)

See the image. Someone Have this problem?![enter image description here][1]

http://imageshack.us/f/5/24mv.png/

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... This is a sign that the GPS can't get a fix on your location. So it could be that you are not in a good location for getting a GPS satellite signal? A possible work-around is to turn on the option of determining your location via wireless tower triangulation. Have you tried that?